# Deleting a Parent Record from a Look-up Table using a Join

Tags: mysql, join

I'm having trouble with `SqlFiddle` hanging so will try to explain simply with tables here.

I have three tables:

1. Orders
2. Items
3. Look-Up Table

The Look-Up table is necessary because of the way I receive data so I extract it into a table with single-items with `OrderID` and `ItemID`

**Item Types**

`+----+----------+---------+
| ID | ParentID |  Name   |
+----+----------+---------+
|  1 | NULL     | Clothes |
|  2 | 1        | Shirts  |
|  3 | NULL     | Food    |
|  4 | 3        | Steak   |
+----+----------+---------+`

**Orders**

`+----+---------+--------+
| ID | OrderID | ItemID |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 | 1,2,3  |
|  2 |       2 | 1,3    |
+----+---------+--------+`

**Look-Up Table**

`+----+---------+--------+
| ID | OrderID | ItemID |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |      1 |
|  2 |       1 |      2 |
|  3 |       1 |      3 |
|  4 |       2 |      1 |
|  4 |       2 |      3 |
+----+---------+--------+`

I now want to do join that grabs all of the item names for each order but I don't want "Parent Items" if a "Child Item" exists (e.g. if the order has `Clothes` and `Shirts` I don't want `Clothes`.

I am not sure why this Select/Delete query is challenging me so as I've done a number of them but it is escaping me for some reason.

Any `Joins` I do, even if I join either/both the `Item Types` table or the `Look-up Table` twice get me only:

1. The Single Child Record

`Select  L.ID,S.ID,S.ParentID from`Look-up Table`L
Inner Join Orders O
On L.OrderID=O.ID
Inner Join`Item Types`S
On L.ItemID=S.ID
Inner Join`Item Types S2
On S.ParentID=S2.ID`

2. Both the Parent Records

Perhaps I've been working on this way too long because the answer seems obvious and I've done plenty of these this week but somehow this one is escaping me.

When SqlFiddle is back-up I will post one to make this a lot easier to debug, any thoughts in the interim appreciate.

Comment: It's challenging because of the poor design of the tables. Orders should be normalized into 2 tables: orders and order_items. item_types seems to contain items and types. Not sure because of how you relate the tables together.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Right I get that. However for simplicity sake I described my tables as per the example, in actuality the 'ItemTypes is a hierarchical table that would not lend itself to being two or more related tables so I',m stuck with what I have here.